# draw line and color the area above in indicator in Trading View with Pine Script

Tags: pine-script-v5

I want to draw a horizontal line at fixed value 30.000 and color the area above in light green in the DMI Indicator. How is this possible?

Thanks

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Directional Movement Index", shorttitle="DMI", format=format.price, precision=4, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
lensig = input.int(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="DI Length")
up = ta.change(high)
down = -ta.change(low)
plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
trur = ta.rma(ta.tr, len)
plus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(plusDM, len) / trur)
minus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(minusDM, len) / trur)
sum = plus + minus
adx = 100 * ta.rma(math.abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), lensig)
plot(adx, color=#F50057, title="ADX")
plot(plus, color=#2962FF, title="+DI")
plot(minus, color=#FF6D00, title="-DI")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hline and fill functions

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_fill
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_hline

```
hline(30, title = "30 Line", color=color.blue, linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=2)

fill(30, 100, color = color.new(color.green, 90))
```